# Nodejs module mysql2 not working with google app engine

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform

I am unable to deploy my nodejs express server with socketio to google cloud app engine. When google cloud runs the app. It gives me with this error message.

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '('
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:931:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1035:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:903:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/lru-cache/dist/cjs/index-cjs.js:5:36)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1015:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1035:10)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! smart-extension-express-app@1.0.0 start: `node index.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the smart-extension-express-app@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2024-01-22T12_28_59_547Z-debug.log
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "smart-extension-express-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^16.3.2",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "http": "^0.0.1-security",
    "mysql2": "^3.7.1",
    "socket.io": "^4.7.4"
  }
}
```

```
app.yaml

runtime: nodejs
env: flex

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1

network:
  session_affinity: true
# [END appengine_websockets_yaml]
```

I have tried to remove and try deploying multiple times trying each module to see what works and not.